# Request stream fail to write

Tags: c#, http

I have to upload a large file to the server with the following code snippet:

```
static async Task LordNoBugAsync(string token, string filePath, string uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest fileWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    fileWebRequest.Method = "PATCH";
    fileWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false; //this line tells to upload by chunks
    fileWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    fileWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "PHOENIX-TOKEN " + token;
    fileWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    fileWebRequest.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
    fileWebRequest.Proxy = null;

    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath) )
    {
        fileWebRequest.ContentLength = fileStream.Length; //have to provide length in order to upload by chunks
        int bufferSize = 512000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int lastBytesRead = 0;
        int byteCount = 0;
        Stream requestStream = fileWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.WriteTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;

        while ((lastBytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != 0)
        {
            if (lastBytesRead > 0)
            {
                await requestStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, lastBytesRead);
                //for some reasons didnt really write to stream, but in fact buffer has content, >60MB                   
                byteCount += bufferSize;
            }
        }
        requestStream.Flush();
        try
        {                    
            requestStream.Close();
            requestStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
        try
        {
            fileStream.Close();
            fileStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
    }
    ...getting response parts...
}
```

In the code, I made a HttpWebRequest and push the content to server with buffering. The code works perfectly for any files under 60MB.

I tried a 70MB pdf. The buffer array has different content for each buffering. Yet, the request stream does not seem to be getting written. The bytecount also reached 70M, showing the file is properly read.

Edit (more info): I set the break point at requestStream.Close(). It clearly takes ~2 mins for the request stream to write in 60MB files but only takes 2ms for 70MB files.

My calling:

```
        Task magic = LordNoBugAsync(token, nameofFile, path);
        magic.Wait();
```

I am sure my calling is correct (it works for 0B to 60MB files).

Any advice or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: `byteCount += bufferSize;` should be `byteCount += lastBytesRead;` for one thing.

Comment: "Yet, the request stream does not seem to be getting written" - what do you mean? What are you actually observing?

Comment: @JonSkeet When I use 60MB files and set the breakpoint at WriteAsync, it clearly takes some time to write the stream.
However, with 70MB files, it simply just takes >1ms and go to the next method. If the request (with content stream) is sent, the server tells me nothing can be found (ie no content for the server to be processed).

Comment: @Tim1234, just my guess, do you config your server (probably IIS) to accept the request with size > 60MB?

Comment: @KimHoang Thank you for your comment. The server is a commerial server for CMS (Content Management System). I cannot configure the server but I assume size limit is not that low (60MB) since the server is for large enterprises.

Comment: Well have you stepped through the method to see whether the loop is actually being entered, etc?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, the loop is entered and as I mentioned that 60MB< files work perfectly without any corruption of content. I can download back the 60MB pdf file and use it without issues. This is where the problem confuses me.

Comment: So have you validated that after it's looped, and once you've fixed the bug with `byteCount`, it's actually copied as much data as you expect? Have you looked at what's happening at the network level, to see whether it appears to genuinely be sending the data? Are either of your `catch` blocks being hit? (I'm assuming that's not your real error handling...)

Comment: Oh, and have you tried disabling write buffer streaming (set the `AllowWriteBufferStreaming` property to false).

Comment: @JonSkeet I validated byteCount and the buffer array (nothing wrong). They are working fine and I did not catch any error. I set `AllowWriteBufferStreaming` to false to upload large files. If the line is commented, I can still send small files (10MB<) to server without timeout issue.

Comment: Okay, so you should next look at what's happening on the network. See whether it's actually trying to send the data. Use something like Wireshark or Fiddler2.

Comment: @JonSkeet The request is indeed sent. The server responded me with 404 which I found in its documentation means the PATCH request gave no content for the server.